# Writing a Credit Score Program. Can't figure out how to get my int value to work

Tags: c#

I'm trying to write a program that enters credit card scores and eventually averages them out. The values must be between 300-800, I'm using an int for my CreditScore. I know the problem is that every time I try to enter the value, I get the error message I created for when a value is outside the range. However I'm not sure how to fix this problem because I obviously can't set the int to just 300 and 800 since there is still a wide range of numbers in between. I'm fairly new to C# and would appreciate any help.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CreditScores
{
    class Program
    {//Joshua Belcher
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int CreditScore = 0;
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a Credit Score");
            CreditScore = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            if ((CreditScore <= 300) && (CreditScore >= 800))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Continue");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error, value not accepted");
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have reversed your conditions... and the if can never be true.  Read it aloud to yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if ((CreditScore <= 300) && (CreditScore >= 800))
```

How can any number be less than or equal to 300 and at the same time greater than or equal to 800?

You have your signs mixed up.

```
if ((CreditScore >= 300) && (CreditScore <= 800))
```

Comment: @laxplayerj93 That's why I like to write this type of comparison as `300 <= CreditScore && CreditScore <= 800`.  It's closer to the natural math expression of `300 <= CreditScore <= 800`.

Answer (score 0):

Credit fix essentially alludes the way toward questioning missteps and blunders that can show up in your credit report. In the event that you think a thing that shows up on your report is incorrect, you can request that the [credit authority confirm].